# LQRQ (low quality review queue) has been extremely slow for at least last ~ 3 hours

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, low-quality-posts

All the other review queues I tried are working just fine. Everything else on the site I've tried has loaded fine.

However, the LQRQ is extremely slow for some reason.

For example, it takes on an average between 20 and 40 seconds to post to

```
stackoverflow.com/review/task-reviewed/#######
```

Is the team aware of this? Are they making changes to that queue or something?

Comment: What is LQRQ? When did we become Abbreviation Overflow?

Comment: I just spent a few minutes investigating the problem. About 5 review items was all I could stand to look at it. Every time I look in the review queue, I can't help but think to myself that we need some more automatic filters. My mashing the delete button isn't enough to make the crap go away. Interestingly, though, the audits still work at full speed.

Comment: @CodyGray because audits caching...?

Comment: Agreed, it is indeed running at a snails pace... which is apparently a [top speed of 50yds per hour](http://www.snail-world.com/snail-facts/)

Comment: It is probably a queue overflow. Just stop using it and it will be faster for everyone else ^^

Comment: @CodyGray For me, the audits are just as slow as the rest of the queue.

Comment: Yeah, something's odd there; investigating

Comment: @CodyGray I thought a lot of LQ was sent there for human confirmation because it failed automated smell test filters; is that no longer the case (with should be closed/not an answer) flags being the primary inputs now?

Comment: @DanNeely There are still automated system flags for failing the "low quality" test that push posts to the queue, but it is vastly filled with very low quality and not an answer flags.

Comment: Yes, this was already the case yesterday. I considered posting it, but I figured it was probably going to get fixed anyway once the SE employees got back from the weekend. :) It was about 20 seconds delay per item.

Comment: Yeah, there are automatic filters that get content into these queues. But the false positives I see are astonishingly low. Same deal as my Spam filter—I never look at the Spam box anymore and haven't had to in years. Why should we have to manually review stuff that the system is correctly flagging as crap?

Comment: @CodyGray A lot of posts that go into the queue are manually flagged be users. Probably like all of the ones older than a month or so and some new ones too. I don't have stats on my statistics there, but I'd guess that I end up recommending deletion/closing 70% of the time, and leaving open 30% of the time. I don't agree with you that it's that accurate for the manual ones. For example, people just posting the answer as all code end up there, and those should be left open, not deleted. Make a comment asking them to explain , sure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically, SQL Server took umbrage at a particular query. For no sensible reason whatsoever, I needed to restructure some queries to stop the optimizer choosing a pathological plan (and yes, we know all about `OPTIMIZE FOR` etc).

Before: 17731.2ms

After: 55.1ms

Should be happier now.